# Mono for android, Changes not reflect

Tags: mono, xamarin.android

I am a new user of mono for android. I have created a new mono android application and deployed it successfully. Now I have made some changes in the project but unfortunately when I run the application, these changes does not reflect on the screen. Waiting for your reply.

Regards

Muhammad Kazim

Answer (score 0):

You should build and deploy the application again to see the changes reflected.

Comment: I press the F5 button for this thing and in my opinion it build and deploy both. So it should not be the problem.

Comment: @MuhammadKazim what about removing the application from the device/emulator and deploy it again?

Comment: Yes it works. but I cannot do it again and again. Too much time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

My issue has been solved. Actually I was making a mistake that I do not click on ‘OK’ button on the “Running Devices” window.  Actually It is not 100% my mistake. In my opinion this screen should come in front of the screen despite of hidden behind other screens. Thanks for your support.

Comment: In that case you had to run the application manually in the device. Mono for Android would not automatically run it unless you chose the device or you set an automatic default one.